# "No such module" error when archiving

Tags: ios, xcode, build, frameworks

My Swift 4 app rebuilds and runs successfully on all simulators except for `Generic iOS Device`. If I try to archive it or do a rebuild on `Generic iOS Device`, I get a `No such module` error relating to one of my pod frameworks.

I tried adding the framework to `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`, and that removed the error, but then it fails on the next pod framework, and so on. I have tried all sorts of paths in `Framework Search Paths` with no luck.

Currently, the value is set to:

[image]

I even tried deleting the workspace, the pod lock file, and the pods folder, and then I did a `pod install` to rebuild everything. Again, it rebuilds clean on any simulator except the generic one. On the generic one, I get `No such module` on all import statements for pod frameworks.

Any suggestions appreciated, as this problem has me completely stalled, since I can't get a release out.

Comment: Did you clean your project delete derived data and run it ?

Comment: I had, but I just tried it again. Did Clean, Clean Build Folder, and deleted Derived Data. It then builds and runs successfully on my iPhone 7 Plus. However, when I try to archive against the same device, I get the `No such module` errors.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For me what fixed it was removing one line from my Podfile and rerun `pod install`.

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
```

I think the version of the pods was not aligned with the version of my target, causing this issue.

Comment: This was helpful for me. I simply bumped my platform # to match my minimum deployment target.

Comment: Thank you! :) I was stuck on this issue for days, trying tons of configuration modifications on the project.

Comment: Thanks, worked. Besides I had to remove Pods folder, Podfile.lock, .xcworkspace files. And run pod install again.

Comment: @Naloiko Eugene suggesting to remove (any) .lock file is terrible advice (unless you understand the consequences).

Answer (score 14):

I was able to fix the problem editing the ios version line in the Podfile to match the Project target version (10.0 in this case) in Info.

```
  #Podfile
  platform :ios, '10.0'
```

[image]

Finally I had to run

```
pod update
```

After that, I was able to `Archive` my project selecting `Generic iOS Device`

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had selected a Device on Xcode when archiving, choosing Generic iOS Device solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to check the project settings by going to **Build Settings**, find **Framework Search Paths** and add `$(SRCROOT)` and be sure it's recursive.

Comment: Your answer made me realize I added a new target (as an extension). Updating that new target's Framework Search Paths fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I kept facing the issue "No such module" while archiving the app.

I tried this [approved answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49047208/8557882) and it worked perfectly but, a new warning was appearing in my Podifle.

So I did the below and it worked without any warning.

Podfile :

[image]

XCode -> Targets -> My App -> General :

[image]

switched iOS from 10.0 to 11.0 and then everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like by opening up the project by double clicking `Runner.xcworkspace` instead of `Runner.xcodeproj`, xcode can finally figure out where everything is. Even though you can still debug in an emulator and on a connected phone from the `.xcodeproj` file...

Seems strange that it would fix it. But I'm happy to have an Archived build now.

[Check out this link for more info](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43986)

Answer (score 1):

There is another case similar to the same error. when you have an Embedded Framework project with min iOS 10 (Any iOS Device arm64, arm7) while I am archiving the build of the project with min deployment version iOS 11(Any iOS Device amr64) in Xcode 12.5.1.

I have to change the min deployment version of the Embedded Framework project to iOS 11(Any iOS Device amr64) to match with my project's deployment version.

Answer (score 0):

first build your project `command + b` and see if the frameworks are in red when you look at then at the right sidebar, if they are, xcode did not find your files on the specified path, if not, building and then archiving should work

Comment: I'm not quite sure where to look for the frameworks. Under `Pods/Frameworks` all of the frameworks are red. Under Frameworks in the project folder, none of them are red. However, I did discover that there is no framework matching the one in the error message.

Comment: If the pods are red then the path is not correct, or you do not have access rights to it

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to archive by re-creating the project from scratch. I created a new project, used the same pod file to install the pod libraries, then copied everything over from the other project. I am now able to archive it and push it to the store. Must have been some corruption or a rogue setting.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the module which couldn't be found was a dynamic Obj-C framework with a minimum deployment target higher than my application project's minimum deployment target. Bumping my minimum version fixed it, but you could drop the version on the framework instead.