# “No such module 'Kingfisher'” error when archiving

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode12, kingfisher

I run or build an app successfully but when I archive an app, I have an error "**No such module 'Kingfisher'**" after I archived in Xcode 12.1.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9kQM.png
I made an app with min iOS 9.0.
I've tried the solution from the link ["No such module" error when archiving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48695303/no-such-module-error-when-archiving) but it didn't work. The error is just the same.
But, the answers on the link are mostly users build on iOS 10 or 11 and they said it worked.
I've tried reinstalling the pods, clearing derived data, but it doesn't work. In my Podfile uses iOS 9 like the image below.
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujUSD.png
Should I upgrade the iOS version from iOS 9.0 to be higher?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if it is 100% related. But it seems that Kingfisher is supporting minimum iOS version 10.
So for your question yes. I’d try to raise it.

Podspec - https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/blob/master/Kingfisher.podspec

Answer (score 0):

a) Go to Pods products group and select all `pods` framework

b) Open build settings and select Architecture section

c) Set 'Standard Architectures (arm64, armv7) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD) for `Debug` and `Release` mode

[image]

I had this kind of issue. Fixed for me. Try this.