# How to bypass error in unsigned xcarchive?

Tags: ios, swift, xcarchive

I am trying to generate an unsigned xcarchive using the following command:

```
xcodebuild -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyScheme -configuration Release clean archive -archivePath buildArchive/MyApp.xcarchive CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY='' CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
```

However, this keeps failing at

```
error: no such module 'RxSwift'
import RxSwift
```

Although pods seem to be successfully installed in the beginning of the process:

```
Prepare packages

note: Using codesigning identity override: 
ComputeTargetDependencyGraph
note: Building targets in dependency order
note: Target dependency graph (14 targets)framework RxCocoa' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RxRelay' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RxRelay' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RxSwift' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RxSwift' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
```

Does anyone know how I can bypass this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["No such module" error when archiving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48695303/no-such-module-error-when-archiving)